# How to fetch data before fetching other data Vue 3

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to fetch all posts where the username is in the user's following array. But I need to wait until the user data is loaded before I can fetch the posts.

### HomeView.vue

```
import PostComponent from '@/components/PostComponent.vue'
import useHomePosts from '@/composables/useHomePosts'
import useAuth from '@/composables/useAuth'
const { posts, getPosts } = useHomePosts()
const { userData } = useAuth()
getPosts(userData.value.following)
```

I tried using asynchronous lifecycle hooks like onMounted and onBeforeMount, however the ref just returns with null.
I also tried putting the two composables into 1 file, but it still resulted in the same thing.

## EDIT

Here is the parts of my useAuth and useHomePosts relevant to the question

### useAuth.js

```js
export default function useAuth() {
    const userData = ref(null)
    const unsubscribeFromUser = ref()
    async function findUser(email) {
        try {
            const queryData = query(dbUsersRef, where('email', '==', email))
            const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(queryData, (docs) => {
                docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    const user = {
                        id: doc.id,
                        ...doc.data()
                    }
                    userData.value = user
                 })
             })
             unsubscribeFromUser.value = unsubscribe
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        if (user) {
            await findUser(user.email)
        } else {
            userData.value = null
            unsubscribeFromUser.value()
        }
    })
}
```

### useHomePosts.js

```
export default function useProfile() {
    const posts = ref(null)
    const unsubscribeFromPosts = ref(() => {})

    async function getPosts(following) {
        try {
            console.log(following)
            const queryData = query(dbPostsRef, where('username', 'in', following), orderBy('createdAt'))
            const unsubscribeFromPosts = onSnapshot(queryData, (docs) => {
                posts.value = []
                docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    const post = {
                        id: doc.id,
                        ...doc.data()
                    }
                    posts.value.push(post)
                })
                posts.value.reverse()
            })
            unsubscribeFromPosts.value = unsubscribeFromPosts
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS Promise, I don't know how is built your useAuth and useHomePosts, but if it launches a fetch you can just return a Promise. It will look after that like this:

```
useAuth().then(
    (response) => {
        // You can make what you want here it's when the fetch is over example
        if (response.userData.value.following) {
            return getPosts(response.userData.value.following) //will return post with your userDataFollowing
        }
})
```

If you can add to your post your useAuth() and useHomePosts(). (without sensible data) I'll maybe be able to help you more.

[Javascript promise (Chained)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises)

Hope it helps you ! :)

EDIT

I don't know where your `useAuth` come from but I will use findUser for my example, you need to return a promise so for that you can modify your function like that :

```
async function findUser(email) {
  try {
    const queryData = query(dbUsersRef, where('email', '==', email));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(queryData, (docs) => {
      docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const user = {
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        };

        userData.value = user;
      });
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      unsubscribeFromUser.value = unsubscribe;
      resolve(queryData); // The treatment is over
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like that:

```
findUser('exemple@email.com')
  .then((user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user);
      // you can get your posts here or whatever it is it will be launch when user is found
    } else {
      console.log('Nothing found');
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Still hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it doesn't work, but I updated the question to include the relevant parts of useAuth and useHomePosts.

Comment: The useAuth comes from the parent function that is exported. I edited my question to include that in case it was confusing. I will try the code that you sent now.

Comment: I can't use findUser because I do not know any user data when loading the page, which includes the email.